# how to adjust client size in python

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I can adjust window size with `win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 100, 100, True)`. However, the border of window may differ in computers. Is there any function I can adjust client size directly?

```
l1, t1, r1, b1 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
l2, t2, r2, b2 = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
client_h = b2 - t2
client_w = r2 - l2
border_l = ((r1 - l1) - (r2 - l2)) // 2
border_t = ((b1 - t1) - (b2 - t2)) - border_l
```

For example, I expect the client size to be 100 and 100. But `win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 100, 100, True)` only set the window size to be 100 and 100 (client size smaller than 100).

Comment: Why don't you calculate the border dimensions upfront and only then *MoveWindow*?

Comment: @CristiFati Since the border dimensions are not fixed, it varies with computers

Comment: yes, it means that on different computers, the formulas you shared will yield different results => different heights/widths.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AdjustWindowRect` to calculate the right window size based on your desired client size.  Here is the Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrect

I don't know how to call it from Python but if this win32gui is good it should provide a wrapper for it, or you could call it yourself with some Python FFI library.

Comment: That calculates the rect values before creating the window, while here the window is already created.

Comment: If the window is not created, you can pass the result of `AdjustWindowRect` to `CreateWindowEx`.  If the window is already created and you're resizing it, just pass its results to `MoveWindow`.  What's the problem?

Comment: Ah yes, was thinking to smth else when I wrote the comment.